# Does Gradle Groovy plugin support continuous builds?

Tags: gradle, groovy, continuous-integration

I have a Groovy 2.4.x project, and am trying to make use of Gradle's [continuous build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/continuous_build.html) feature. However, when I run:

```
./gradlew build --continuous
```

I get errors:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/sandbox/myapp$./gradlew build --continuous

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :build from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--continuous'.

* Try:
Run gradle help --task :build to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I'm wondering if this is because I'm using the Groovy plugin (`apply plugin: groovy`)...are continuous builds not available for Groovy apps? If so, how can I get continuous builds working for my app (or is that not possible)? Otherwise, what is going on here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of groovy, or the groovy plugin

Comment: I tried it with gradle 3.4 and groovy but don't see it working yet. I only see in the console `Continuous build is an incubating feature` Changing sources does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "continuous build" feature wasn't released until version 2.5: https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/release-notes .